# Increase the height of DIV with jQuery animate, without pushing the content down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this code,

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-line"></div>
<div id="main-menu"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-line {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#main-menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#main-menu").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: "100px"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: "30px"
    });
});
```

[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JuG6X/)

I have made the middle DIV expand its Height with jQuery `animate` function. but the problem with this is it pushes down the bottom DIV.

How to make it expand over the bottom DIV without pushing it down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change html to

```
 <div id="header-line"></div>
 <div id="content">
     <div id="main-menu">Expands on hover</div>
 </div>
```

Change jquery to

```
$("#main-menu").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: "100px"
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true, false).animate({
        height: "30px"
    });
});
```

Change style to

```
#header-line {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#main-menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
```

The main aim is to put the div inside the other div, then it won't put the bottom div down.

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JuG6X/11/)

Comment: In case you would like to control the duration of the animation add another property called duration inside `.animate(..)`, `{duration: 100}` for more information click [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a css problem, you have to add position: absolute; to the green DIV, but you will have to fix the width: [Test](http://jsfiddle.net/JuG6X/5/)

```
#main-menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do can be achieved by wrapping the two elements in a wrapper with `position:relative`

This way you can absolutely position the child elements, your content area & the expanding bar within the parent (the new div)

By setting them as absolute they will stay in position and the expanding div will essentially overlap the content one underneath:

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/JuG6X/6/

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, You just had to set new height to content div. (`#content`)

http://jsfiddle.net/JuG6X/

Answer (score 1):

Somethinglike this :

```
#header-line {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#parent{
    position:relative;
}
#main-menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:100;
}
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    /* take into account : borders, margin, previous sibling height */
    top:30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/7ytgy/

It's one solution among many others. you need to add a parent `#parent` with relative positionning, it will act as a reference for its children.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your **css**,

```
#header-line {
    height: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#main-menu {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
    z-index:0;
    top:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Working Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/JuG6X/14/